# Declaring an incomplete type template parameter in place in-the argument list

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, declaration

I have seen use like:

```
boost::error_info<struct tag_name, std::string> name_info;
```

Here `tag_name` names an incomplete type and the `struct` keyword preceding it seems to declare it in-place, instead of the slightly more verbose:

```
struct tag_name;
boost::error_info<tag_name, std::string> name_info;
```

What is the relevant part of the standard that allows this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§3.4.4/2 specifies how elaborated-type-specifiers, in any situation, are looked up and what effect they may have:

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key* and
>   this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name* [..] **the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the
>   *class-name* as described in 3.3.2**.

Then §3.3.2/7(.2) reads

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows: [..]
>   for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> *class-key
>   identifier*
>
> if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope,
>   the identifier is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that
>   contains the declaration; **otherwise, except as a `friend` declaration,
>   the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope
>   that contains the declaration.**